# What's the mean of "QVector<QVector<QVector<T>>> vector"?

Tags: qt, qvector

This is the code:

```
QVector<QVector<QVector<T>>> vector
```

I've tried search from internet, nothing help

Comment: vector is a 3 dimensional qvector

Comment: If I write like "QVector<QVector<QVector<int>>> vector",  can you give me a simple example to help me understand this point

Comment: it is "vector of vectors of vectors of T" where T is some type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mean `QVector<QVector<QVector<T>>> vector` is 3D - array storing objects of type T. If you need example for int, you can find it here:

[Qt 3D-array with Qt-Objekts like QVector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16971704/qt-3d-array-with-qt-objekts-like-qvector)

Each dimension can be different.